# cant go through JQuery method within if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This jQuery method attr doesn't work inside `if` condition

```
let regex1 = /^admin$/ ;
let regex2 = /^admin$/ ;
$("#ancor").click(function () { 
  if (($("#username").val() == regex1 ) && ($("#password").val() == regex2) {
    $("#ancor").attr("href", "FormEditor.html")
  } else {
    alert("username or password my be not correct")
  }  
});
```

I have an anchor tag with `id="ancor"` and I want to check if the username and password match my `regex1` and `regex2` to add `href` to that ancor to redirect the page called FormEditor

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test  you need to use the test method, not equality

Comment: Also keep in mind, credential validation should never be done client side if you are trying to do any serious authentication controls.

Comment: You don't test regex patterns with comparison operators such as `==` or `===`. You need a proper regex expression [RegExp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and then use `test()` method.

Comment: @ambianBeing https://jsfiddle.net/oe2Lmc5p/  "proper regex" ?

Comment: If this is for anything other than testing or proof of concept, then you ***really*** need to move the credentials check to the server side.

Comment: @Taplar yeah the wording is a little off here. Meant to say either a valid regex pattern string like in OP or make one via `RegExp()` and use `test()`

Comment: how stupid i am , i have forget test my regex , thanks alot  Taplar &  ambianBeing